# HTAccess: Internal redirect directories (or symlink?)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, symlink

I'm currently struggelling with the following situation which I want to solve with HTacess redirection.

- The main CMS is running in the root directory /.
- In the subdirectory /shop/.. there is a shop (based on another system)

Till now everything is fine: The main website is rewritten by /.htaccess and the shop by /shop/.htaccess

Now I want to access an english version of the shop with /en/shop/.. 
Actually the calls should only be redirected to the shop-system in the directory /shop (but with the url /en/shop/.. in the browser)

I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/shop/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /shop/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which is not really working.

My question is: Can I solve that with simple htaccess or would it be a more elegant solution to make a symlink /en/shop => /shop ?
(Are there any performance differences between these solutions?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is this htaccess located? in root or shop?

Comment: There is a htaccess in the root (for the CMS) as well as in the shop folder (for the shop system)

The RewriteRule I mentioned above is in the root folder

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code at the root folder `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+en/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop/ en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ $1 [L,NC]
```